# Edit / remove page sizes from Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, customizing

When editing document properties in Inkscape, I have a long, hard-coded pre-determined list of random document sizes (*see illustration below*). I want to add to, and remove from, said list.

The issue has been mentioned a few times on launchpad (bug [171808](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/171808) and [926209](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/926209)), and in the former a user says “This should be closed as fixed. It all is available in trunk.”

That was written in 2012, and it is not available in the current stable Inkscape (0.92.1 / r15371).

**Question: How can I download, edit and compile the source code, so I can remove and add document sizes to my Inkscape?**

[image: Inkscape document properties]

Answer (score 0):

I've spent too much time, but I've found the answer myself.

1. Go to [inkscape.org](https://inkscape.org/en/release/0.92.2/source/) and download source
2. Open src/ui/widget/page-sizer.cpp and edit the page sizes
3. In the directory of the source:

   `./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   make
   make install`

To compile there are quite a lot of dependencies. This was where my time was spent, and I had to add unstable sources to fulfil the requirements.

[image: My new page properties dialog]